# Jekyll bad uri bad request line

Tags: jekyll

For some reason I started getting this error and I'm not sure why. I haven't been doing anything differently, it just started doing this. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

```
Bryans-MacBook-Pro:website bryan$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website/_config.yml
Configuration file: /Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website
       Destination: /Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.114 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website'
Configuration file: /Users/bryan/Dropbox/Websites/Clients/website/_config.yml
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2017-10-31 11:06:45] ERROR bad URI `d??\x1EG?7?\x16??\x06???\x16????\\,?\x01\b?oq?K\x00\x00(?,?+?$?#?'.
[2017-10-31 11:06:50] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x03\x14?????.?z?m??\x02®?,??("p?M%?'\x17?N\x00\x00.?,?+?$?#?'.
[2017-10-31 11:06:50] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x01????ۙ\x10o?/?\\????k?<r\x18ofGL>`\x02?Ć\v\x00\x00\x12\x00/\x003\x005\x009?\t?'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are receiving this answer it is because your browser is trying to load the page via http**s** and not http

Comment: Yes: I recently installed the Firefox HTTP to HTTPS addon, which caused this behavior (error / warning) in Jekyll ... https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6507#issuecomment-497404604